# What is a good Java design to call through methods?

Tags: java

This the following a good design if I wanted to call a method to a method?
The code below is this just an example.

```
public Enigma(){
    String sentences = "This "; 
    method1(sentences);
}

public void method1(String x){
    x = x + "a ";
    method2(x);
}

public void method2(String x){
    x = x + "test ";
    method3(x);
}

public String method3(String x){
    x = x + "!";
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to answer this; you've written code that accomplishes nothing, and are asking whether it's a good design.  I don't think so.  The best design for writing code that accomplishes nothing is `public Enigma() { }`.  If you want this code to accomplish something, please let us know what you wanted it to accomplish, and we can tell you whether it will work and whether it's a good design.

Comment: It may be pointless to say with the sample code, but otherwise, find good parameter names. If the `x` is not the same, find three different parameter names.

Comment: The chaining of method calls as in the example, there is nothing wrong with it. In some cases it will be good design, it depends.

Answer (score 0):

If those methods are only called from the constructor, then there's no point in making them public.

Also, usually you'd call method1 from the outside after creating the Enigma object.

Finally, as you may know chaining calls like that may lead to code that is difficult to understand and follow.

But if your question is related to "does this work", the answer is simply yes :)

Comment: I disagree--I don't think it works, if I'm guessing correctly what he's trying to do.

Comment: "The code below is this just an example". So I take it as he understands that code does nothing apart from string concatenation, but for no purpose. The question is if chaining calls like that is valid in Java (at least I got that as the question) :P

Comment: I disagree the other way around. If each method is easy to understand in isolation and does its own job, the method call chaining is the good solution. Of course, just splitting a coherent method in three would by silly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on the right track. Even if your example doesn't do anything concrete, I believe it is a good idea to point out possible flaws.

1. The class name has to be the same name of its Java file. For example, your class "Enigma" has to be written in the "Enigma.java" file. Otherwise, problems can appear. Often it is a good thing to remember.
2. Note that you can call `method3` from `method2` in a way that uses the output of this function.

   ```
   public method2(String x) {
       x = x + "a ";
       x = x + method3(x)
   }
   ```

   Note that this example is only to show you how you can retrieve the value of the method you just called. You can always simply call this method the same way you call a `void` even if the method returns something. Both options work, it is for you to decide what your program has to do and how, depending on the context.

Overall, the correct Java syntax for your class is this one:

```
public class Enigma {
    //put your class properties here

    public Enigma(){
        String sentences = "This ";
        method1(sentences);
    }

    public void method1(String x) {
        x = x + "a "; method2(x);
    }

    public void method2(String x) {
        x = x + "test "; method3(x);
    }

    public String method3(String x) {
        x = x + "!";
        return x;
    }
}
```

After this, if you are using `Enigma`a as an object, you might want to add a constructor. If `Enigma` is not an object, use `static` methods by writing `static` just before your method return type in the declaration. For example: `public void method1(String x) {` would become `public static void method1(String x) {`. Doing so when possible is a good way to keep simple a program that acts like a script.